# How to detect a bending person using Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, detection, matlab-cvst

I'm facing a problem while using a computer vision system toolbox (Matlab)
`vision.PeopleDetector` System object to detect the person when it is bending. Since this tool is to only detect upright person, it failed when the bending posture is not upright.

I did try using `regionprops` that worked with segmented silhouette of the bending figure but since I'm using Gaussian mixture model to segment, the results are bad as well.

Anyone has good suggestion on detecting a bending person? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to clarify, are you working with a video? Is your camera stationary?  In that case, you should be able to use `vision.ForegroundDetector` to detect anything that moves, and then use `regionprops` to select the blobs of the right size. If `regionprops` does not work for you, you may want to try using morphology (`imclose` and `imopen`) to close small gaps and to filter out noise.

Also, if you are working with a video, then you can use `vision.KalmanFilter` to track the people. Then you would not necessarily have to detect each person in every frame. If a person bends down, you may still be able to recover the track when he straightens back up.

Another possibility is to try the upper body detection with `vision.CascadeObjectDetector`. If you rotate the image 90 degrees, you should be able to detect the upper body of a bending person.

Yet another possibility is to train your own "bending person detector" using the `trainCascadeObjectDetector` function.

Comment: Yea, it is a video taken with static camera. Thank you so much for your recommendation. I will update which approach work better.